# What's the difference between these 2 Mule flows

Tags: mule

```
<flow name="webserviceFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:7079/service">
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" serviceClass="MyService"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="MyServiceImpl" />        
</flow>
```

**And**

```
<flow name="webserviceFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:7079/service"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" serviceClass="MyService"/>
    <component class="MyServiceImpl" />        
</flow>
```

Comment: Not sure why, looks like a legit question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the flow stays as it is in your question, they're functionally equivalent.

If you would want to make this flow also accessible for direct requests, say over the VM transport, by using a `<composite-source>`, then you'll want to circumscribe the `cxf:jaxws-service` to the `http:inbound-endpoint` so the CXF logic doesn't kick in, as shown here:

```
<flow name="webserviceFlow1">
    <composite-source>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="directAccess" />
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:7079/service">
            <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SOAP" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" serviceClass="MyService"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
    </composite-source>
    <component class="MyServiceImpl" />        
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know something like '<composite-source>' exists :)